# hornetq "Cannot find queue info for queue <other server uuid>", core bridges?

Tags: jboss, jms, hornetq, jms-topic

I have very limited knowledge of HornetQ configuration, but I'll try to explain my problem best I can.

**Here's the setup:**

There are several STANDALONE JBoss (6.1.0Final) instances running on one network. This means, they are not clustered, they have deployed different application, and in general they should not interfere with one another. Each JBoss has HornetQ configured with one topic.

There are NO core bridges (or any bridges at all) configured in `deploy/hornetq/hornetq-configuration.xml`, in fact this is pretty much standard conf file, with little to no changes from the one that is supplied with jboss (I'm happy to post it if someone asks tho).

During startup of ALL JBoss instances:

```
07:37:40,489 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] Server is now live
07:37:40,489 INFO  [HornetQServerImpl] HornetQ Server version 2.2.5.Final (HQ_2_2_5_FINAL_AS7, 121) [7d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f] started
```

of course the UUID is different for each server.

However, for some servers HornetQ also creates bridges (WHY?):

```
07:37:40,764 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Connecting bridge sf.my-cluster.e479de63-9d3b-11e3-b089-2c768a5d0e23 to its destination [7d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f]
07:37:40,878 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Connecting bridge sf.my-cluster.f9d193de-5bfa-11e3-9491-2c768a5d129f to its destination [7d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f]
07:37:40,980 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Bridge sf.my-cluster.e479de63-9d3b-11e3-b089-2c768a5d0e23 is connected [7d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f-> sf.my-cluster.e479de63-9d3b-11e3-b089-2c768a5d0e23]
07:37:40,980 INFO  [BridgeImpl] Bridge sf.my-cluster.f9d193de-5bfa-11e3-9491-2c768a5d129f is connected [7d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f-> sf.my-cluster.f9d193de-5bfa-11e3-9491-2c768a5d129f]
```

First question: Why does this happen, why does HQ create this bridges even if no configuration of them is specified?

**Here's the problem:**

every few seconds, HornetQ spews

```
2014-02-26 08:17:28,379 ERROR [org.hornetq.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl] (Thread-3 (group:HornetQ-client-global-threads-903011273)) Failed to call listener: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find queue info for queue 80ce792b-382b-4d22-99ae-60cf25e305027d0a3341-9eb0-11e3-980d-2c768a5d129f
    at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.onNotification(PostOfficeImpl.java:278) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.management.impl.ManagementServiceImpl.sendNotification(ManagementServiceImpl.java:654) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl.removeBinding(PostOfficeImpl.java:511) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl$MessageFlowRecordImpl.removeBinding(ClusterConnectionImpl.java:886) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl$MessageFlowRecordImpl.doBindingRemoved(ClusterConnectionImpl.java:874) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.server.cluster.impl.ClusterConnectionImpl$MessageFlowRecordImpl.onMessage(ClusterConnectionImpl.java:695) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:866) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:44) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:983) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [:1.7.0_25]
```

Now this is a little "random", some of the JBoss servers don't log it at all, some log it multiple times with different UUIDs, it all depends on how many bridges it created during startup...

Why does this happen to me? What can I do to stop it. I want all of the servers to work independently of each other.

I'm happy to provide more information that could help solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bridges are created by automatic clustering. Your two servers are probably part of the same UDP configuration (look at the group UDP IP and port on the hornetq-configuration) and they are forming a cluster.

Probably when you shutdown one of the nodes you didn't have the nodes when you restarted it  and the bridges were not being able to reconnect or something like that.

On this case you were not supposed to form a cluster and the nodes were finding each other and hence finding the bridges for the cluster inter communication.

change the UDP IP and port and these servers will be independent.. or if you don't need clustering replace the configs from the ones on standalone non clustered.

Comment: UDP addresses in HQ configuration were the same, however each server had it's own port (XYY96, where XYY is unique server id, ie 101, 102, 201, etc). However, I've added `<clustered>false</clustered>` directive in the configuration, removed the `broadcast-groups` and `delivery-groups` configuration altogether, and it seems that the issue was fixed after server restart.